# How can I get term aggregation to match a total string?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have a some data that I'm aggregating with elasticsearch 1.5.2 and when I do a terms aggregation on a field like `city` the buckets don't match full strings from the field. Ex.) If city is St. Louis then one bucket would be `St.` and the other `Louis`. Does anyone know how to make sure that when it aggregates it goes into a `St. Louis` bucket?

note: This may be caused from the data being analyzed which I'm pretty sure breaks up strings when comparing and searching etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct. So you simply need to map your `city` field as a `not_analyzed` string using this mapping:

```
{
  "your_type" : {
    "properties" : {
      "city" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "index" : "analyzed",
        "fields" : {
          "raw" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then you can simply run your aggregation on the `city.raw` field (which contains the un-analyzed value, i.e. `St. Louis`) instead of `city`, which is analyzed and breaks up the content into several tokens (i.e. `st` and `louis`).

If you know in advance, you're never going to need the analyzed field, you can simply store the `not_analyzed` field like this (i.e. no need for the `fields` part declaring a multi-field):

```
{
  "your_type" : {
    "properties" : {
      "city" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "index" : "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```